# Como fazer rolamento suave com botão ou âncora?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rolamento

Preciso de uma ajuda em `css`, e `js`.

Preciso de um js que faça que quando eu clicar no botão down, ou up, role o scroll de uma div para determinado tamanho:

Link de exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/A64S2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão, usando jQuery/animate:

```
var frame = $('.texto');
$('.botoes a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fazerScroll($(this).parent().hasClass('up')); // chamar a funcao controlando se o elemento pai tem a classe 'up'
});

function fazerScroll(direcao) {  // uso a flag "direcao", que pode ser true (up ou false (down)
    var scrollAtual = frame.scrollTop(); // controlar a posicao atual do scroll
    var novaPosicao = direcao ? scrollAtual - 200 : scrollAtual + 200; // subir ou descer consoante aq flag direcao
    frame.animate({ // usar o animate para ser mais suave o scroll
        scrollTop: novaPosicao
    }, 1000); // duracao: 1000milisegundos
}
```

Exemplo:

```js
var frame = $('.texto');
$('.botoes a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fazerScroll($(this).parent().hasClass('up'));
});

function fazerScroll(direcao) {
    var scrollAtual = frame.scrollTop();
    var novaPosicao = direcao ? scrollAtual - 200 : scrollAtual + 200;
    frame.animate({
        scrollTop: novaPosicao
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.mural {
    width:100%;
    background:black;
}
.texto {
    margin:20px auto;
    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    background:#8f528f;
    padding:20px;
    color:white;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.botoes {
    float:right;
    display:inline-flex;
    color:black;
    background:white
}
.up {
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mural">
    <div class="texto">
        <p>textotextotexteoxtexoteodooeifeodfdafdsfsdfsd</p>
        <p>textotextotexteoxtexoteodooeifeodfdafdsfsdfsd</p>
        <p>textotextotexteoxtexoteodooeifeodfdafdsfsdfsd</p>
        <p>textotextotexteoxtexoteodooeifeodfdafdsfsdfsd</p>
        <p>textotextotexteoxtexoteodooeifeodfdafdsfsdfsd</p>
        <p>textotextotexteoxtexoteodooeifeodfdafdsfsdfsd</p>
        <p>textotextotexteoxtexoteodooeifeodfdafdsfsdfsd</p>
    </div>
    <div class="botoes">
        <div class="up"><a href="">UP</a>

        </div>
        <div class="down"><a href="">DOWN</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[exemplo no codepen](http://jsfiddle.net/6Q9EA/1/)

Comment: perfeito...vlw amigo!

Comment: Ótimo que pude ajudar... esta resposta usa jQuery, se preferir MooTools diga :)