# Scroll suave sem âncoras

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olhem só esse site: [www.kinfolk.com](http://www.kinfolk.com)

A navegação horizontal em baixo do carrossel de fotos tem um *ease* suave na interação, e não usa âncoras.

É só um scroll convencional com smooth e acho que tem um *motion blur* também.

Alguém sabe como chegar nesse resultado?
Eu já vi o tal de [niceScroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/), mas ele me pareceu travado, não suave o suficiente. Não como este exemplo.

Comment: Veja se isto é o que você está procurando: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23631/rolagem-suave-na-p%C3%A1gina

Comment: O estilo do slider me lembrou do bxSlider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este é o plugin utilizado:

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

E este é o github do projeto:

https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Opa,

Muito legal o efeito, não conhecia ainda esse tipo de slider. Dei uma pesquisada e achei algo que pode ser útil:

- http://portfoliojs.com/

Quem sabe utilizando a base do plugin citado acima você consiga implementar algo parecido utlizando outro plugin pra easing do scroll horizontal ou até mesmo css3, dai vai depender da sua necessidade em relação a suporte de navegadores.

icul8r.